# SystemParametersInfo and SPI_SETCURSORS fails with no error

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

This one is really driving me nuts. I've searched and searched and feel like I'm the only one having this issue. So I'm hoping for some kind of sanity check here.

First, the context--I'm creating a simple replacement shell for a dedicated gaming machine. Part of the shell is hiding the cursor. I've found a lot of samples showing how to do this by editing the registry and then telling Windows to refresh the cursors.

The registry code was no issue and works fine. However, the subsequent call to SystemParametersInfo fails every single time. Worse yet, a follow up call to Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 0.

Initially I tried the code on a Windows 8.1 machine and chalked it up to it being some kind of Windows 8 issue. However, the code is not working on Windows 7 (x64 SP1) either.

Here is the sample code that illustrates the issue I'm having:

```
class Program
{
    //a
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    //b
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    //c
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    //d
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, string pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    const uint SPI_SETCURSORS = 0x0057;
    const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    const uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

    static uint _pvParam = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //a
        var a = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, IntPtr.Zero, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
        var ax = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        //b
        var b = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
        var bx = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        //c
        var c = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, ref _pvParam, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
        var cx = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        //d
        var d = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, null, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
        var dx = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Console.WriteLine("a: {0}\tax: {1}", a, ax);
        Console.WriteLine("b: {0}\tbx: {1}", b, bx);
        Console.WriteLine("c: {0}\tcx: {1}", c, cx);
        Console.WriteLine("d: {0}\tdx: {1}", d, dx);

    }
}
```

My results are always:

```
a: False        ax: 0
b: False        bx: 0
c: False        cx: 0
d: False        dx: 0
```

I would love it if someone could run this code tell me if it works for them. Or better yet point out the obvious problem I'm missing. :)

EDIT: Tried this method signature as well and it did not work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);
```

<strike>EDIT 2: Also of note: you can call the method without passing SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE and it will return "True". However, it will not successfully reload the cursors.</strike>

Here is basically what I'm trying to do: http://www.daveamenta.com/2013-08/programmatically-update-the-mouse-cursors-with-powershell/

Comment: Better is to call `SetSystemCursor`.

Comment: The problem with SetSystemCursor is that it isn't called until the shell loads. So you end up seeing the cursor as wininit and winlogon etc load. The registry solution allows you to hide it entirely across reboots etc. I could just permanently change it to a blank cursor, but I want the ability to toggle it. It may seem like a small point, but the whole idea is to remove any trace of "Windows-ish" look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a repro for that in a C++ program as well.  Unusual bug.  It is sulky about you using SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE.  Just remove that flag and you're good to go.

Watch out with those overloads btw, you'll need to delete the *uint* version.

Comment: That did it! At first I thought it didn't work, but the issue was where I was updating the registry. As soon as I realized that goof, sure enough I got "True" and the cursor updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the import be as this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);
```